# IAM policy for access to s3 bucket allows unintended object get operations

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Given these bucket keys:

my-permtest/
my-permtest/rootfile.txt
my-permtest/Finance
my-permtest/Finance/financefile.txt
my-permtest/Collections
my-permtest/Collections/collectionfile.txt
my-permtest/Shared
my-permtest/Shared/sharedfile.txt

and this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListAllMyBuckets",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowedListAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest/Collections",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest/Shared"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAllObjectActionsNotExplicitlyDenied",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*Object*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllFinanceAccess",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest/Finance"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Why am I able to perform gets and puts on s3://my-permtest/Finance/financefile.txt ? 
I expect that the "Sid": "DenyAllFinanceAccess" block should forbid this access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one turned out to be simple.
I needed to also deny all actions to all objects below the finance key
specifically, the

```
    "Sid": "DenyAllFinanceAccess",
```

block needed to be modified to read:

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyAllFinanceAccess",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest/Finance",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-permtest/Finance/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: will accept someone else's answer if they show a better way, otherwise will accept my own when the site permits.